# Batch script to automate mapping of network drive but unable to detect network drive

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a script to automate the mapping of 2 network drives, using the identical code except changing the IP address accordingly, only 1 network drive can be mapped successfully.

I have tried mapping the network drive manually and it works normally.

```
if EXIST \\172.168.101.187\smb (
set shareExistsTX=1
echo Sender Share exist. 
) else (
set shareExistsTX=0
echo Sender Share Dont exist. 

)

if EXIST Y:\ (
set driveExistsTX=1
echo Drive Y:/ Unavailable
) else (
set driveExistsTX=0
echo Drive Y:/ available
)


if %shareExistsTX%==1 if %driveExistsTX%==1 (
echo deleting network drive
net use /delete Y: /y
set driveExistsTX=0
)


if %shareExistsTX%==1 if not %driveExistsTX%==1 (echo mounting smbserver Sender
net use Y: \\172.168.101.187\smb /persistent:Yes /user:user password
)

set driveExistsTX=
set shareExistsTX=

if EXIST \\172.168.101.188\smb (
set shareExistsRX=1
echo Receiver Share Exist
) else (
set shareExistsRX=0
echo Receiver Share Dont exist. 

)

if EXIST Z:\ (
set driveExistsRX=1
echo Drive Z:/ Unavailable
) else (
set driveExistsRX=0
echo Drive Z:/ available
)


if %shareExistsRX%==1 if %driveExistsRX%==1 (
echo deleting network drive
net use /delete Z: /y
set driveExistsRX=0
)


if %shareExistsRX%==1 if not %driveExistsRX%==1 (
echo mounting smbserver Receiver
net use Z: \\172.168.101.188\smb /persistent:Yes /user:user password

)

set driveExistsRX=
set shareExistsRX=
pause
```

I am supposed to map both network drives, however only 172.168.101.187 is mapped whereas there is an error message of "Receiver Share Dont exist." which means that the script is not able to detect the network drive of 172.168.101.188

Comment: All the code is needed because I am tasked by my lecturer to go through a step by step guide to map the network drive and display output messages along the way. I've tried changing the code to if EXIST \\172.168.101.188\smb\* and I'm still not able to map it

Comment: because you missed my comment completely, you are not adding the last backslash and dot. `if EXIST \\172.168.101.188\smb\*.` see the answer below.

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake while typing. I tried with the last backslash and dot and it failed too. The reason being is because the network drives that I am mapping to are currently empty and therefore there would be no files within the share to try this code.

Comment: see my edit in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To directly address your issue, test existance of items inside the share, not the share itself:

```
if EXIST \\172.168.101.188\smb\*.
if EXIST \\172.168.101.187\smb\*.
```

**Edit**
However, based on your comment, you have nothing in the folders, so let's create something, test it and delete it again. like this:

```
type nul>\\172.168.101.188\smb\_tmp
if EXIST \\172.168.101.188\smb\*.
type nul>\\172.168.101.187\smb\_tmp
if EXIST \\172.168.101.187\smb\*.
```

then after the mapping completed in the script, add:

```
del /Q Y:\_tmp
del /Q Z:\_tmp
```

or

```
del /Q \\172.168.101.187\smb\_tmp >nul
del /Q \\172.168.101.188\smb\_tmp >nul
```

So to take your actual script and make all the changes to it, we will get this, which should work:

```
@echo off
type nul>\\172.168.101.187\smb\_tmp
type nul>\\172.168.101.188\smb\_tmp
if EXIST \\172.168.101.187\smb (
set shareExistsTX=1
echo Sender Share exist. 
) else (
set shareExistsTX=0
echo Sender Share Don't exist. 

)

if EXIST Y:\ (
set driveExistsTX=1
echo Drive Y:/ Unavailable
) else (
set driveExistsTX=0
echo Drive Y:/ available
)


if %shareExistsTX%==1 if %driveExistsTX%==1 (
echo deleting network drive
net use /delete Y: /y
set driveExistsTX=0
)


if %shareExistsTX%==1 if not %driveExistsTX%==1 (echo mounting smbserver Sender
net use Y: \\172.168.101.187\smb /persistent:Yes /user:user password
)

set driveExistsTX=
set shareExistsTX=

if EXIST \\172.168.101.188\smb (
set shareExistsRX=1
echo Receiver Share Exist
) else (
set shareExistsRX=0
echo Receiver Share Dont exist. 

)

if EXIST Z:\ (
set driveExistsRX=1
echo Drive Z:/ Unavailable
) else (
set driveExistsRX=0
echo Drive Z:/ available
)


if %shareExistsRX%==1 if %driveExistsRX%==1 (
echo deleting network drive
net use /delete Z: /y
set driveExistsRX=0
)


if %shareExistsRX%==1 if not %driveExistsRX%==1 (
echo mounting smbserver Receiver
net use Z: \\172.168.101.188\smb /persistent:Yes /user:user password

)
del /Q Y:\_tmp>nul
del /Q Z:\_tmp>nul
set driveExistsRX=
set shareExistsRX=
pause
```

Then maybe a slightly different version of this?

I do not need to check existance of drive, I just try and map it regardless:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "shares=\\172.168.101.187\smb \\172.168.101.188\smb"

for %%i in (%shares%) do (
    type nul>%%i\_tmp
    if "%%i"=="\\ppsm202zatcwi\Mac" set "dr=Y:"
    if "%%i"=="\\172.168.101.188\smb" set "dr=Z:"
    if exist %%i\*. (
      net use !dr! %%i >nul 2>&1 && echo Mapped !dr! to %%i
      del /Q !dr!\_tmp>nul
      ) else (
        echo Sharename %%i not found unable to map !dr!
   )
 )
 pause
```